# Proving that the inverse of a matrix squared is equal to first squaring the matrix then taking its inverse

Tags: matrices

If I have a matrix A, I want to show that $$(A^{-1})^2=(A^2)^{-1}$$

Sorry if it is an obvious/simple proof. Does this even require proving? This is my first time on this site. Hope someone can help

Comment: Say you had a matrix $B$, and you wanted to prove it was the inverse of $A^2$. What would you try to show?

Comment: Look at what your proof wants. It says prove that $(A^{-1})^2$ is the inverse of $A^2$. So  what is the definition of a matrix to be the inverse of another matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Use the associativity of matrix multiplication
$$\begin{align}
(A^{-1})^2\cdot (A^2) 
&= (A^{-1}A^{-1})(AA) \\
&= A^{-1}(A^{-1}A)A \\
&=A^{-1}IA \\
&= A^{-1}A \\
&= I
\end{align}$$
Verifiying that $(A^2)\cdot(A^{-1})^2 = I$ is almost the same.

Comment: You must calculate the left multiplication by $A^2$ also. Isn't it?

Comment: @ManjoyDas Yes, but the process is pretty much the same :)

Comment: yeah.. that's correct :)